# removeEventListener for window.onstorage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, addeventlistener, use-effect, removeeventlistener

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) describe two possible ways to listen to storage events, `window.addEventListener('storage', () => { ... })` and `window.onstorage = () => { ... }`. In a React app, if I used addEventListener inside of a useEffect hook, I'd want to return the cleanup function `window.removeEventListener('storage', ... )` to avoid a memory leak after the component unmounts.

However, `window.onstorage = () => { ... }` does not offer a way to remove the event listener. Does this mean that it's safe to listen to storage events this way without returning a cleanup function in a useEffect hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a listener like

```
window.onstorage = () => { ... }
```

You are technically allowed to only have one listener in your application on storage. However if `window.addEventListener` you can have as many event listeners as you want and cleanup requires the same function reference that was passed to `addEventListener` to be passed on to `removeEventListener`

You can clean it up by setting the storage listener function to null

```
useEffect(() => {
    // other code
    return () => { window.onstorage = null };
}, []);
```